# conditionally adding logo to iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, amazon-s3, cross-domain

I am using iframes to serve content that I want people to be able to embed on their own sites. I am also embedding these iframes on my own site (mysite.com in the code below).

I am using the following javascript function

```
function addLogo() {
    if (window.top.location.host != "mysite.com") {
        $("#logo").html('<a href="...mysite.com" target="_parent"><img src="...mysite.com/logo.png" border="0"></a>');
    }
}
```

to check where the iframe is embedded. If the iframe is embedded anywhere other than the my site, jquery is used to add a small logo / back-link to the frame.

The main site is hosted on a shared server and the embedded html and js files are in an Amazon S3 bucket. Having the js file check on the location of the parent window is causing security errors in both Firefox and Chrome

Firefox:

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'host'

Chrome:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "...amazon.s3Bucket" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "...mysite.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Is there a way to use js to conditionally add the logo  based on top.host without causing these errors or creating security problems?

I am hoping to stick with js so that I can serve the iframe content (html and js) from Amazon S3

Comment: You're violating [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: Is there any way to have js query the parent of the iframe without violating the same-origin policy?

Comment: Yes, if you can control both pages, please check [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3076648/1169519).

Comment: @Teemu It looks like window.postMessage will give me the functionality I want. Thanks